# General random walk expected first exit time via martingale

Tags: markov-chains, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

$x_t$ is a random walk with nonnegative integer time $t$ on the integer set $\mathbf Z$ with transition probability $P(x_{t+1}\mid x_t)=p\mathbf 1(x_{t+1}-x_t=1)+q\mathbf 1(x_{t+1}-x_t=-1)$, $p>0,\,q>0$, $p+q=1$ and $p\ne q$. I know $y_t := \big(\frac qp\big)^{x_t}$ is a martingale. Given $x_0=0$, $\tau:=\min\{t:x_t=a>0\,\vee x_t=-b\}$ where $a,b\in \mathbf N$.

Can anyone remind me of the martingales that give the expected value and the variance of the first exit time $\tau$, perhaps utilizing $y_t$? What is the relationship between the martingales and the probability generating function of the first exit time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so very simple. The extra martingale is merely the natural "speed function" $z_t:=x_t-t(p-q)$. It is obvious that $z_t$ is a martingale. Now let $\tau:=\inf\{t: x_t\ge a\,\wedge\, x_t\le -b \}$. By Doob's optional stopping theorem, $\big(\frac pq\big)^{x_0}=\mathbf E[y_\tau]=P\big(\frac pq\big)^a+Q\big(\frac pq\big)^{-b}$, where $P=\text{Prob}(x_\tau=a)$ and $P+Q=1$. We can solve for $P$ and $Q$. Applying again Doob's optional stopping theorem $x_0=\mathbf E[z_\tau]=aP-bQ-(p-q)\mathbf E[\tau]$. We can now solve for $\mathbf E[\tau]$.